# Ruby error NoMethodError for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm following the Treebook tutorial on teamtreehouse.com (making a facebook clone) using rails. I have created a userfriendships controller and am getting this error when trying to reference a friend's full name in my index.html page of the friendships view: **undefined method `full_name' for nil:NilClass**. The problem occurs on line 4 here, (this is /views/user_friendships/index.html)

```
<div class="page-header">
  <h1>Friends</h1>
</div>
<hr />
<% if @user_friendships.empty? %>
<em>No <%= params[:list] %> friends yet!</em>
<% end %>

<% @user_friendships.each do |friendship| %>
 <% friend = friendship.friend %>
 <div id="<%= dom_id(friendship) %>" class="friend panel">
    <div class="panel-heading">
      <span class="pull-right label>"><%= "#{friendship.state}".upcase %></span>
      <h3 class="panel-title"><%= friend.full_name %></h3>
    </div>
    <div class="panel-body">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-1">Put gravatar url here</div>
          <div class="col-md-11">
            <em>Friends since time_ago_in_words ago</em>
          </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="panel-footer clearfix">
        <%= link_to "Update friendship", edit_user_friendship_path( friend.profile_name), class: 'btn btn-primary pull-right' %>
    </div>
 </div>
<% end %>
```

Here's the User Friendships Controller:

```
class UserFriendshipsController < ApplicationController
before_filter :authenticate_user!

  def index
    @user_friendships = current_user.user_friendships.all

  end

  def new
    if params[:friend_id]
      @friend = User.where(profile_name: params[:friend_id]).first
      raise ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound if @friend.nil?
      @user_friendship = current_user.user_friendships.new(friend: @friend)
    else
      flash[:error] = "Friend required"
    end
    rescue ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound 
      render file: 'public/404', status: :not_found

  end

  def create

    if params[:user_friendship] && params[:user_friendship].has_key?(:friend_id)
      @friend = User.where(profile_name: params[:user_friendship][:friend_id]).first
      @user_friendship = UserFriendship.request(current_user, @friend)
      respond_to do |format|
        if @user_friendship.new_record?
          format.html do
            flash[:error] = "There was a problem creating that friend request."
            redirect_to profile_path(@friend)
          end
          format.json { render json: @user_friendship.to_json, status: :precondition_failed }
        else
          format.html do
            flash[:success] = "Friend request sent to #{@friend.full_name}."
            redirect_to profile_path(@friend.profile_name)
          end
          format.json { render json: @user_friendship.to_json }
        end
      end
    else
      flash[:error] = "Friend required"
      redirect_to root_path
    end
  end

  def edit
    @friend =  User.where(profile_name: params[:id]).first
    @user_friendship = current_user.user_friendships.find(params[:id])
  end

  def destroy
    @user_friendship = current_user.user_friendships.find(params[:id])
    if @user_friendship.destroy
      flash[:success] = "Friendship destroyed."
    end
    redirect_to user_friendships_path
  end

  def accept
    @user_friendship = current_user.user_friendships.find(params[:id])
    if @user_friendship.accept!
      flash[:success] = "You are now friend with #{@user_friendship.friend.full_name}"
    else
      flash[:error] = "That friendship could not be accepted."
    end
    redirect_to user_friendships_path
  end

  def block
    @user_friendship = current_user.user_friendships.find(params[:id])
    if @user_friendship.block!
      flash[:success] = "You have blocked #{@user_friendship.friend.full_name}."
    else
      flash[:error] = "That friendship could not be blocked."
    end
    redirect_to user_friendships_path
  end

  private
  def friendship_association
    case params[:list]
    when nil
      current_user.user_friendships
    when 'blocked'
      current_user.blocked_user_friendships
    when 'pending'
      current_user.pending_user_friendships
    when 'requested'
      current_user.requested_user_friendships
    when 'accepted'
      current_user.accepted_user_friendships
    end
  end

  private
  def user_friendship_attributes
    params.require(:user_friendship).permit(:user, :friend, :user_id, :friend_id, :state)
  end

end
```

Lastly, I will include the user friendships model:

```
class UserFriendship < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user
    belongs_to :friend, class_name: 'User', foreign_key: 'friend_id'

    state_machine :state, initial: :pending do
        after_transition on: :accept, do: :send_acceptance_email
        state :requested

        event :accept do
            transition any => :accepted
        end
    end

    def self.request(user1, user2)
      transaction do
        friendship1 = create(user: user1, friend: user2, state: 'pending')
        friendship2 = create(user: user2, friend: user1, state: 'requested')

        friendship1.send_request_email
        friendship1
      end
    end


    def send_request_email
        UserNotifier.friend_requested(id).deliver
    end

    def send_acceptance_email
        UserNotifier.friend_request_accepted(id).deliver
    end

    def mutual_friendship
        self.class.where({user_id: friend_id, friend_id: user_id}).first
    end
# Manually updating the state to avoid callbacks and infinite loops
    def accept_mutual_friendship
        mutual_friendship.update_attribute(:state, 'accepted')
    end
end
```

I'm aware that I must have to change this somehow, but am at a loss as to how to do that. I would like this page to display all of the friends that a user has, either in an accepted or pending state. Can anyone see what I need to do?

Thanks!

EDIT: If I change the views/user_friendships/index.html to **friend.full_name** instead of **@friend.full_name** I still get the same error. I can verify that the users currently in the db all have a valid first and last name (so the full name method should work).

Another EDIT: Here is a rails console entry showing that I do have userfriendships in the database:

```
2.1.2 :003 > UserFriendship.all
  UserFriendship Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "user_friendships".* FROM "user_friendships"
 => #<ActiveRecord::Relation [#<UserFriendship id: 1, user_id: 6, friend_id: nil, created_at: "2014-10-04 14:20:42", updated_at: "2014-10-04 14:20:42", state: nil>, #<UserFriendship id: 2, user_id: 6, friend_id: nil, created_at: "2014-10-04 14:21:32", updated_at: "2014-10-04 14:21:32", state: nil>, #<UserFriendship id: 3, user_id: 6, friend_id: 3, created_at: "2014-10-04 14:21:50", updated_at: "2014-10-04 14:21:50", state: nil>, #<UserFriendship id: 4, user_id: 6, friend_id: 6, created_at: "2014-10-04 14:23:58", updated_at: "2014-10-04 14:23:58", state: nil>, #<UserFriendship id: 5, user_id: 6, friend_id: 6, created_at: "2014-10-04 14:25:05", updated_at: "2014-10-04 14:25:05", state: nil>, #<UserFriendship id: 6, user_id: 6, friend_id: 4, created_at: "2014-10-04 14:25:15", updated_at: "2014-10-04 14:25:15", state: nil>, #<UserFriendship id: 7, user_id: 6, friend_id: 6, created_at: "2014-10-04 20:42:40", updated_at: "2014-10-04 20:42:40", state: nil>, #<UserFriendship id: 8, user_id: 6, friend_id: 6, created_at: "2014-10-04 20:45:44", updated_at: "2014-10-04 20:45:44", state: nil>, #<UserFriendship id: 9, user_id: 6, friend_id: 6, created_at: "2014-10-04 21:38:17", updated_at: "2014-10-04 21:38:17", state: nil>, #<UserFriendship id: 10, user_id: 6, friend_id: 6, created_at: "2014-10-09 16:53:44", updated_at: "2014-10-09 16:53:44", state: "pending">, ...]>
2.1.2 :004 >
```

Another Edit: Here is the user model models/user.rb:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

    validates :first_name, presence: true

    validates :last_name, presence: true

    validates :profile_name, presence: true, 
                             uniqueness: true,
                             format: {
                                with: /\A.+\z/,
                                message: "must be formatted correctly"
                             }

    has_many :statuses
    has_many :user_friendships
    has_many :friends, -> { where user_friendships: { state: 'accepted'} }, through: :user_friendships
    has_many :pending_user_friendships, -> { where state: 'pending' },
                                      class_name: 'UserFriendship', 
                                      foreign_key: :user_id
    has_many :pending_friends, through: :pending_user_friendships, source: :friend

    def full_name
        first_name + " " + last_name
    end

    def gravatar_url
        stripped_email = email.strip
        downcased_email = stripped_email.downcase
        hash = Digest::MD5.hexdigest(downcased_email)
        "http://gravatar.com/avatar/#{hash}"

    end
end
```

Comment: Well let's look at this in pieces... What page are you on! Where is its corresponding action? So where do you think the error is occurring? It's not the new action is it....

Comment: Am I correct in believing it's the index action? Yes, I agree the new action is not the problem, and I referenced the pages/files that I'm presenting here.

Comment: what I don't understand is that in your index action you have a `.all` on  @user_friendships but in your `index.html` you are not iterating through the collection.. what are you trying to show in your view? it looks like something i would use in a `show` action if i'm honest.... also if your user doesn't have a full_name then it will throw that error

Comment: Hi Rich,

Thanks for your attention. I edited my question based on your last comment. I am iterating through a list of all the friends, I hadn't shown that in my original question so they are now edited to show the entire file.

I'm interested in displaying a list of friends in this index page as you say you would do with a show action. I could be convinced either way; how would you model this index page? I could tackle that once I can figure out what is going wrong with my pages referencing the friend object.

Comment: can you check your Friend records and ensure all records have a `full_name`, or you can wrap friend.full_name in `<% if friend.full_name %> <% end %>`let me know

Comment: Hi Rich,

I wrapped it in the if friend.full_name % end %> tags and it gave me the same error this time in reference to the if statement. From what another commenter said I think this is because I don't have friend initialized as a constant. Do you think that could be the problem?

Comment: out of interest what does `<h3 class="panel-title"><%= friendship.friend.full_name %></h3>` give you

Comment: That gives me the same error. I also tried user_friendship.friend.full_name and user_friendships.friend.full_name. I tried just user.full_name and it gave me the undefined local variable `user` error, not sure if that illuminates anything.

Comment: ok so `full_name` is available as an instance of a user, so what about <h3 class="panel-title"><%= friendship.user.full_name %></h3>, also have you tried putting your question to the Treehouse forum?

Answer (score 0):

instead of @friend.full_name  use friend.full_name

You have define it here <% friend = friendship.friend %>

Comment: If I replace that in the index page I still get the same error: **undefined method full_name for nil:NilClass**

`<% friend = friendship.friend %>
     <div id="<%= dom_id(friendship) %>">
       <div class="panel-heading">
         <h3 class="panel-title"><%= friend.full_name %></h3>
       </div>
    </div>
   <% end %>`

Comment: nil means that you don't have any records.  Use `rails console` and do things like `User.all` and `UserFriend.all` etc to find records.

Comment: Okay, that got me somewhere. I was able to find all of my users with the User.all but a UserFriend.all and Friend.all told me I have an uninitialized constant.

 So I think I need to initialize the constant Friend, right? I will do some searching on that.

Comment: what about `UserFriendship.all` ?

Comment: That returned a list of friendships. I will update the question with that log.

Answer (score 0):

So I am pretty sure what happened was that some of my database tables were dropped during a rake db:migrate that I ran. I did it because I was looking at a similar rails app that was building a social network site and switching my database back and forth between the two. Not sure how or why migrate deleted something ( i believe it deleted first and last name which is why full_name would be an nil error). I am going to revert to a previous commit where everything was working and try to rebuild from there.

Thanks for the posts!

tl;dr: dont run db:migrate without knowing what you're doing